# How to maneuver one person to the right of Imam during Salat?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, muslim-practices

While during salat there are only two persons (an imam and a jamaat) and the jamaat initially stand to the left of the imam (the correct one should be on the right & the Imam already in Salah before the Jamaat comes), and the imam wanting to maneuver the jamaat to the right, how should the imam maneuver him? especially if the jamaat is older than the imam? (a kid would be way easier to maneuver)

Comment: Doesn't the imam has a mouth and could clear things before starting the prayer?

Comment: @Medi1Saif I mean the Imam already in salah but then a Jamaat comes

Comment: That is strange a good imam wouldn't start before a congregation is possible. And if you mean a congregation outside a mosque then the question is does this second person knows the rules is he really having the intention to follow the imam etc. well the imam may give him a sign. But if this is a second congregation in a mosque most scholars say such thing is not allowed. But so far which situation applies is unclear to me. Finally in Arabic jamah refers to a group of at least 2 people so one person isn't a jamaat.

Comment: @Medi1Saif It is common in Shafi'i majority countries for someone to join another person who is praying alone. So, the jama'ah here is not something that was agreed beforehand.

Comment: @Crimson that is what I meant, the Imam wasn't an Imam until a person joined him, and that person is likely don't understand that he should stay on the right of the Imam